# In which directory does npm postinstall run?

Tags: npm, post-install

I am running `npm install infojunkie/musicxml-mma#npm-install`. That module includes a postinstall script that generates a config file which should contain the absolute path of the installed module.

The postinstall shell script uses `$(pwd)` to find the current path, which I had assumed would be the installation directory:

```
sed -r "s#/full/path/to/module#$PWD#" configrc.example > config.rc
```

However, when I examine the generated `config.rc` file, I see a temporary directory:

```
[...] /home/kratib/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clonetLJs8x [...]
```

I am interpreting this to mean that the postinstall script is not running in the final installation directory, but in a temporary one.

How can I ensure that the script will run in the final directory? Is there a later lifecycle event that I can use instead of postinstall?